# Iterating throughput dataframe columns and using .apply() gives KeyError

Tags: python-3.x

So im trying to normalize my features by using .apply() iteratively on all columns of the dataframe but it gives KeyError. Can someone help?

I've tried using below code but it doesnt work :

```
for x in df.columns:
      df[x+'_norm'] = df[x].apply(lambda x:(x-df[x].mean())/df[x].std())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to use `mean` and `std` functions inside the apply. You are calculating them each time which that any row is going to get its new value. Instead you can calculate them in the beginning of the loop and use of it in the apply function. Like below:

```py
for x in df.columns:
      mean = df[x].mean()
      std = df[x].std()
      df[x+'_norm'] = df[x].apply(lambda y:(y-mean)/std)
```